# Cross domain tracking with new analytics.js syntax?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics and I am trying to set cross domain tracking for my website. I've read Google's [cross domain tracking guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&utm_id=ad), but I am confused as to how to implement it properly.

The issue I am having is that the example code they give looks nothing like the tracking code I was given through my Google Analytics admin console.

My tracking code looks like this:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'MyTrackingID', 'MyDomain');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

(My actual tracking ID and my domain have been censored out with `MyTrackingID` and `MyDomain`, respectively.)

However, the example tracking code given in the guide looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :
  'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

How do I add the `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'A.com']);` "option" to my tracking code as instructed?

Answer (score 2):

The example tacking code you're referring to is for `ga.js` which is used with standard (non-universal) Google Analytics, as indicated in the [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&utm_id=ad) you provided:

> This information applies to the ga.js tracking method only.

[Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009) uses `analytics.js` tracking code, as can be seen [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009). Therefore, you'd want to refer to this instead:  [Cross Domain Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Analytics admin interface to generate the proper tracking code for you.  It will has an option specifically for multiple top level domains.

- Log into Google Analytics
- Select "Admin" in the orange bar
- Look under "Property" for ".js Tracking Info"
- Set "Multiple top-level domains" to "On"
- Install the new tracking code that it gives you into your website

[image: Google Analytics Multiple top-level domains setting]

---

Edit:  If you have selected the new tracking style, Google no longer gives you a nice user interface these options.  Instead you have to figure out the code yourself manually from their [help document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain)

Based on that documentation, your tracking code should be:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('require','linker');
ga(‘linker:autoLink’,[‘example.com’,‘otherexample.com’]);
ga(‘create’,'UA-XXXXXX-X',{‘allowLinker’:true});
ga('send','pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: It appears this option is only available for `ga.js` (non-universal Google Analytics) and not `analytics.js` which [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) uses.

Comment: Using the `autoLink` plugin is [Experimental](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#overview). The OP, and anyone else reading this, really needs to read that help doc (the same one I already linked to), and output their specific tracking code from the Universal Analytics interface first.